# I have downloaded ubuntu but I don't know how to install it

Tags: 12.04

I had downloaded ubuntu for my laptop but the .iso file download is been able to extract and I have copied the extracted files and softwares and even the settings are changed they
were Internal HHD
     Diskeet Drive
     Usb storage
     CD/R/W-R
and  Onboard NIC
so,the selected option was by me Usb Storage but still when I start the laptop Windows Xp only will start no OS option is asked

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), See also [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) tutorial from the official Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 2):

You need to burn the iso to a cd with a software like cdburnerxp. You shouldn't extract the files.

You may also create a usb stick to start from instead with http://www.linuxliveusb.com or something like it.

Then when you restart your PC, hit (f2 or f8 or f10 or f12 or del) one of these keys takes you into the BIOS menu where you can select to boot from CD/DVD drive or USB drive.

Since you seem a little inexperienced, you should consider to find somebody who has installed Ubuntu before and let him walk you through the steps after that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is youtube link. It will show you following steps:

1. from where to download Ubuntu
2. from where to download software that will help you to burn Ubuntu to USB pendrive or CD/DVD
3. how to open up BOIS on computer startup so that you can burn your USB pendrive or CD/DVD
4. then how to burn the iso to USB pendrive or CD/DVD
5. then how to install Ubuntu step by step, by explaining all options available while installing

[Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows [2014]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo)